# How can there be an inner product space when inner product yields a scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I thought the inner product yields a scalar in both real and complex cases. How can a space be made up of scalars? Taking two vectors $a$ and $b$, $a=(a_1,a_2)$ and $b=(b_1,b_2)$, the inner product is $$( a,b)=(a_1\overline{b_1}+a_2\overline{b_2})$$
That's a scalar. How can there be a space of scalars?

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you are asking. Please *significantly* improve your question.

Comment: Inner product space means a space (*of vectors*) along with an inner product (which is a way of combining two vectors to get a scalar, according to certain rules).  It is not a space where the elements are "inner products."

Comment: While the inner product "yields a scalar", an inner product is a bilinear function, mapping pairs of vectors to that scalar "inner product".  An inner product space is a vector space equipped with an inner product, not a vector space "made up of scalars".

Comment: So it's a space where inner product can be done (that is two vectors satisfying definiteness, positivity, additivity, homogeneity, etc), correct?

Comment: The inner product on $\mathbb{R}$, for example, is just multiplication $(a,b) \mapsto a \cdot b$. The elements of $\mathbb{R}$ are "vectors" in that they are elements of a vector space.

Comment: I think you're confusing the bracket $(\bullet,\bullet)$ of the scalar product, that is a short notation for a function of 2 vector variables $\phi : \Bbb C^2\times \Bbb C^2\to\Bbb C$ defined by $$\phi((a_1,a_2),(b_1,b_2))=(a,b):=a_1\overline{b_1}+a_2\overline{b_2}$$ (analogous to the fact that "$+$" is a shorthand for a function $\Bbb C\times\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$) with the standard notation for a pair $(a_1,a_2)$, which is an element of $\Bbb C\times \Bbb C$. Long story short, there isn't much to do. You can use the $\langle\bullet,\bullet\rangle$ notation for the scalar product, if it helps you.

Comment: So in my case, the inner product space consists of just the vectors a and b? And the inner product result (i.e. a scalar) is not represented anywhere (in any space), correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An inner product space is a linear space, equipped with an inner product on it. So, it's a pair $(X,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$, where $X$ is the linear space and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ the inner product on $X$.